# can't activate rake (= 0.9.2.2, runtime) for [], already activated rake-10.0.2 for []

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to run a simple rake task.  When I do, I get the following error:

can't activate rake (= 0.9.2.2, runtime) for [], already activated rake-10.0.2 for []

I run the gem list command, and it lists rake as having 10.0.3, 0.9.2.2, and 0.8.7.

So, I type gem uninstall rake -v 10.0.3.  According to the prompt, the uninstall was successful - but version 10.0.3 is still there when I do a gem list - and I still get the exact same problem when I try to run any rake task.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: How about `bundle exec` in front of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either :

- run `bundle exec rake` to use the version of rake listed on your `Gemfile.lock` if you don't want to update it
- Update the version of rake used in your `Gemfile.lock` by running `bundle update rake` and then you will be able to use the command `rake` again !

Answer (score 14):

You probably have the older version of rake listed in your `Gemfile.lock`. Try to run `bundle update rake`, which should update everything rake-related and change your Gemfile.lock as well.

Comment: I tried this and it says `Could not locate Gemfile.`